# SOLR Query result not showing new field

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solrconfig

I have added a new sort field in schema.xml, uploaded DIHConfigFile.xml and Schema.xml in SOLR config.

`<field name="recommendationRank" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false"/>`

After this I did run zkcli, restarted SOLR and zookeeper both and also reindexing in solr.

Sorting based on the new field do give me the results back but i dont see the new field itself in the response.
http://localhost:48100/solr/MainSystem1/select?indent=on&q=*:*&sort=recommendationRank_EN_US%20desc&wt=json

Update for query result

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":11,
    "params":{
      "q":"recommendationRank_EN_US:2",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json",
      "debugQuery":"on",
      "_":"1638448595617"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  },
  "debug":{
    "rawquerystring":"recommendationRank_EN_US:2",
    "querystring":"recommendationRank_EN_US:2",
    "parsedquery":"recommendationRank_EN_US:2",
    "parsedquery_toString":"recommendationRank_EN_US:`\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002",
    "explain":{},
    "QParser":"LuceneQParser",
    "timing":{
      "time":11.0,
      "prepare":{
        "time":0.0,
        "query":{
          "time":0.0},
        "facet":{
          "time":0.0},
        "facet_module":{
          "time":0.0},
        "mlt":{
          "time":0.0},
        "highlight":{
          "time":0.0},
        "stats":{
          "time":0.0},
        "expand":{
          "time":0.0},
        "terms":{
          "time":0.0},
        "debug":{
          "time":0.0}},
      "process":{
        "time":9.0,
        "query":{
          "time":8.0},
        "facet":{
          "time":0.0},
        "facet_module":{
          "time":0.0},
        "mlt":{
          "time":0.0},
        "highlight":{
          "time":0.0},
        "stats":{
          "time":0.0},
        "expand":{
          "time":0.0},
        "terms":{
          "time":0.0},
        "debug":{
          "time":1.0}}}}}
```

Comment: You can use the [Field List parameter](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html#CommonQueryParameters-Thefl_FieldList_Parameter) `fl` to specify which fields to include in the response, for example `fl=id,title,recommendationRank`.

Comment: Thanks @EricLavault ! I tried what you suggested but i see all the fields except recommendationRank.

Answer (score 1):

the field name shown is `recommendationRank` and in your query you have `recommendationRank_EN_US`as sort option . Is that a copy field ?

I suggest you do a simple query to see if the document is populated correctly with the new field value after reindexing your docs or not.

say recommendationRank:xyz (some value which you will know as per you indexing  logic from the source system).

Can you share the output of the above query with `debugQuery=on` for further debugging.

Also, i would suggest you enable docValue for the fields which you are using or plan to use for sort/facet/pivot/stat/highlighting etc to avoid high field cache and improve the query performance.

Comment: Yes, its a copy field. Attached response in the question @DineshNaik

Comment: you can clearly see there is no matching records, see  
"response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]}

Comment: yeah i noticed that but its strange since i do see it in the xmls which i indexed.

Comment: One thing I see as strange is why the parsedquery_toString has these special chars appended before actual search text. 
What is the field type definition in your schema for recommendationRank and recommendationRank_EN_US?
"parsedquery_toString":"recommendationRank_EN_US:`\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002",

Comment: Its defined as string, i also tried changing it to int but still the same.

Comment: can you share your schema.xml ( or managed schema) and solrconfig.xml ?